# Containers inside records in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, containers, records

The data structure I have in mind involves a record with a member which stores unique strings.
Abstractly this is the record I have in mind:

```
struct A {
name: string;
neighbors: Set of String;
};
```

But I can't seem to create a Set container inside a record in Ocaml. Given that a Set is a functor and not a traditional type, I am not sure how this can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Set` is a functor that instantiates a new type for each type of set you want; since it needs to know the comparison function, you can't do `string set` like you can `string list` (unless you use `PSet`, the polymorphic set, from [Batteries Included](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org) or extlib).  So:

```
module StringSet = Set.Make(String);; (* or use BatSet.StringSet *)
type record = {
    name: string;
    neighbors: StringSet.t;
};
```

With Batteries' polymorphic sets (be careful with it, as it doesn't type-check that you're using the same comparison function):

```
type record = {
    name: string;
    neighbors: string BatSet.t
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand the difference between a "string list", for example, and the "string set" that you want to build.

For lists, the type is 'a list, because you need to know nothing about the content of the list to build the list. For a set, you want log(N) time access, and for that, you want to organize the set depending on the order of the elements. So, you need to be able to compare them. OCaml provides a default comparison function (Pervasives.compare), but that function is not always the best one : it is expensive to use (for integers for example), and it does not work all the time (it uses a lexicographical order on the structure of the value, that is not always the order you want).

In OCaml, when a type depends on a value, which is the case of the "set", but would also be the case of a "sorted list", you need to use a functor to define the type, and to apply the functor to get the new type.

That's what this code does for you:

> module StringSet = Set.Make(String)

is equivalent to :

```
module StringSet = Set.Make(struct
  type t = string
  let compare = compare
end)
```

where "let compare = compare" means that the comparison function is the default one (the second compare refers to Pervasives.compare). You can use directly "String" instead, as the String modules already contains "type t = string" and "let compare = compare".